# Getting an error with an image URL in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I saved my PNG folder in same folder which contains the main class 
and used that PNG file in an image tag in sample.fxml and tried to display it, which worked fine.

But when I try to map it to a string in main, it shows an error.

I have uploaded the image to show my PNG folder on the left panel.

Sample.fxml

```
<ImageView fx:id="user1" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" x="150.0" y="50.0">
   <image>
      <Image url="@PNG/AceClub.png"/>
   </image>
</ImageView>
```

Main.java

```
for(int i=0;i<suit.length;i++) {
    //  ImageStore.cardimagedeck.put(rank[j]+suit[i],new Image("@PNG/"+rank[j]+suit[i]+".png"));
        for(int j=0;j<rank.length;j++) {
            javafx.scene.image.Image image=new Image("@PNG/AceClub.png");
            ImageStore.cardimagedeck.put(rank[j] + suit[i], image);
        }
}
```

Error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1107)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:617)
        at Card/sample.Main.loadimages(Main.java:35)
        at Card/sample.Main.start(Main.java:18)
```

[application screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHqtZ.png)

Comment: Please post the full code and clarify your intentions. It's unclear what you want to achieve with the code you have provided and neither is it clear what isn't working for you in that code..

Comment: The `@` symbol has [special meaning](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution) in the context of an FXML file. The `String` constructor of `Image` follows [different rules](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html); if the URL has no scheme then the path is treated the same as specified by [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to upload my image from PNG folder in main class. PNG folder in src folder. (src/PNG/AceClub.png)